# Программа в виртальной сети Hamachi Logmein

Tags: сеть

Привет, ребята.

Я новый. Мне нужна помощь. Есть сеть виртуальная Hamachi Logmein и бухгалтерская программа, которая работает через лан как бы: в нем есть клиент и сервер... Через лан она работает на всю, проблем с ним нету, но через виртуалку Hamachi запустить его не смог...

[Logmein Hamachi](https://logmein.ru/RU/products/hamachi/).

Comment: а можно подробнее? где стоит сервер? где клиент? какая адресация? маска? ну и т.д. Задача-то вобщем простая

Comment: Как бы да, запускал много всего через такую сеть, и Удаленный доступ был, и игры и т.д. но данная программа не пошло (Дело такое: Программа бухгалтерска с SQL сервером и клиент , "как бы база и клиент, который может добавлять торавы в базу". В обои концы поставил Hamachi Logmein сеть есть, желтый горит, не моргает. Сервер запускается, а клиент нет ! P.S.: Когда клиент не видит сервера, он вообщем не открывается. Под локальную сеть работает без проблем ... (((